# existence of a complex sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, contest-math, chaos-theory

Let $z_n$ be a sequence of nonzero complex numbers such that $z_{n+1}=z_n^2+z_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Can such a sequence satisfy $\lim_{n\to +\infty}z_n=\lim_{n\to -\infty}z_n=0$ ?

---

A friend from the university showed me this question saying it's a student competition problem from the 90's. None of us and our colleagues was able to solve it, nobody had even an idea how to start the solution.

=======================

*It is NOT a duplicate. There is a big difference between real and complex numbers and sequences, especially when one wants to use the fact that being bounded and monotonic implies convergence, which was the main observation in the linked question!*

Comment: I think this is a classic problem in chaos theory.

Comment: there is a big difference between real and complex numbers... especially when one wants to use the fact that being bounded and monotonic implies convergence...

Comment: I actually mistook this for another problem, the complex quadratic map. I couldn't find your map here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chaotic_maps.

Comment: @DietrichBurde we also must note that the indices are integers rather than naturals in this case!

Comment: One observation, which I think is correct, is that the modulus of all the complex numbers in the sequence must be strictly less than $2$, else the sequence will diverge from left to right.

Comment: Another observation is that we can satisfy the divergence to the RHS if we can at some point make force $z_n$ to be real with $-1 < z_n < 0$. ... At least I think so.

Comment: The answer seems to be "yes". Starting with $z_0=i/2$, both the forward iteration ($z_{n+1}=z_n+z^2_n$) and a backward iteration ($z{n-1)=\sqrt{z_n+1/4}-1/2$, square root with real part $\ge0$) seem to converge to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

NOT AN ANSWER- JUST SOME COMPUTATIONS THAT WERE TOO LONG FOR COMMENT.

Let's compute the inverse recurrence relation using the general solution to a quadratic equation.

$$z_{n+1}=z_n^2+z_n$$

So:

$$z_{n-1}= -\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{1 + 4z_n}}{2}$$

Since we know the sequence converges to the RHS for any real $-1 < z_n < 1$, we could try to solve this problem by just showing the LHS convergence starting at some $-1 < z_n < 1$ and following the above recurrence relation which decrements $n$.

Now, if we have a converging sequence to the LHS, then $z_n$ will tend towards $0$ and so $\frac{\sqrt{1 + 4z_n}}{2}$ will tend towards $\frac12$ and so beyond a certain point, as we go left, we will no longer be able to choose the minus side of the plus-or-minus sign in the above recurrence relation. In other words, for any arbitrarily small $\epsilon$, we'll need to reach a point $m$ such that $|z_m| < \epsilon$ and forall $i < m$:

$$z_{i}= -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{1 + 4z_{i+1}}}{2}$$

We'd also be forced to have $|z_i| < \epsilon$ for all such $i$ all the way to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z_0:=-1/2\;$ and $\;z_{n+1}:=z_n^2+z_n.\;$ It is easy to see that $z_n$ decreases monotonically to $0$. Let $z_{n-1}:=(-1+\sqrt{1+4z_n})/2,\;$ taking the principal branch of square root. Observe that with these definitions, $z_{n+1}=z_n^2+z_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}.$ The first few values for $n<0$ are
$z_{-1}=-1/2+i/2,\;$ $z_{-2}=-0.107+0.636i,\;$ $z_{-3}=0.130+0.504i.$ The result to prove is that if $n<0,\;$ then $|z_{n-1}|<|z_n|.\;$ The proof is not much different than the proof for $n>0.\;$ It depends on finding the approximation $|z_n|\approx 1/|n|\;$ for $|n|$ big enough. In fact, $z_{-n}\approx-z_n\;$ for large $|n|$.

Comment: A concern is that all terms should remain on the same side of the branch cut of $\log$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Surely it is enough that all but finitely many are on the same side such that $0\le\arg(z_n)<\pi.$